# Zoom meeting app does not work (it installs)

Tags: applications

I installed zoom 64 Deb and it worked but when I tried to make a video meeting, it did nothing..

5.1 eOS

Many students use this app and Linux is well supported by zoom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know this app, but have you tried to run Zoom through the terminal. It might tell you something more what's going on.

regards.

Comment: Seems to work now.  Although it does not always remember me.  I don't know if the launch in terminal helped or now.. but menu launching works now too.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried downloading it again? I am using amd 64 in 5.1 without problems.

Answer (score 0):

I just updated my system with the app center application and now Zoom crashes when I try to start a meeting. I tried removing, reinstalling, and installing also the snap version. They install OK, but the application is not responsive.